# Is there a way to refer to rawValue as a different named member in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Swift, if

```
enum Number: Int {
    case One, Two, Three, Four, Five
}

var five = Number.Five
print( five.rawValue )
```

Is it possible to refer to the raw value using a name other than the built-in *rawValue*, e.g. something uniquely descriptive to the case at hand, such as *numberInt* or something like that, e.g.

```
print( five.numberInt )
```

?

Comment: yes, you can. enums do support computed properties. 
So you can just declare the variable with a getter that will return you rawValue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
enum Number: Int {
    case One, Two, Three, Four, Five

    var numberInt : Int { return self.rawValue }
}

var five = Number.Five
print(five.rawValue)   // 4
print(five.numberInt)  // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define a function or a computed property inside the enum that returns the value you need

```
enum Number: Int {
    case One, Two, Three
    func numberInt() -> Int {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```